# Difficulty of comprehension of Japanese in a video and identification of dialect

Tags: dialects, listening

I came across the following video when doing research:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mlkoq4WZrTE&t=358s&authuser=1

At first I could not comprehend at all what was being said, but after listening carefully I could pick up a few words. Generally my listening comprehension isn't that bad, so this caught me off guard.

I think part of the reason is the sound recording and how the sensei in the video is speaking in a rough way.

But I think another aspect is how he is speaking in some dialect (Kyoto?).

So my two questions are:

1) Is the Japanese in this video easily understood by native Japanese speakers?

2) What regional dialect is being spoken, if any?

Comment: I also can't understand what he said except some words. I think he  scarcely opened his month.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I wonder if the students there understood (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) No. I can pick only a few words such as 極意, 回る (with the aid of the gesture), これは, 大概, 息を, これだけじゃ相手, ...

2) Definitely dialectal. Probably western Japan. Maybe Kyushu...? Oh, [this person is from Matsuyama, Ehime](https://aikidoaishinkan.jimdo.com/profile-1/) in the Shikoku island.

Comment: I once learned that in martial arts, 先生 speaks sometimes with soft voices as a way to train listening. I had to raise my volume quite high to hear more-or-less "clearly" before I could distinguish that I could not understand anything because of the words and not because of a lack of volume and not being able to hear anything

Comment: Thanks naruto! Why do you think it is so hard to understand? sound quality, his intonation, or his accent?

Comment: @Locksleyu Everything. I once lived in Ehime and generally comfortable with 伊予弁 spoken by younger people, but his way of speaking is really unclear.